# Disable "click to navigate" icons in Resharper

Tags: resharper

How can I disable the "click to navigate" icons on the left bar?

I believe they are called "gutter" icons but I just didn't find a way to disable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't be disabled, I'm afraid. If you want to, you can log this as a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com